Limit CPU usage by temperature over time gradient
As CPU clock can be limited by thermal thesholds (implemented by CPU vendor firmware / controller or in Linux by /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device* devices), is it also possible to limit by temperature gradient over time?
Eg. when system leaves standby in cold environment, set the clock limits to slowly (over some seconds or minutes) rise core and heatsink temperature, reducing thermal cycling stress?

"time gradient"... Just create a daemon which monitor the temperature and setup the limits.
